# Is it true that uniform convergent families of functions on R, aka {fn}, are also equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that uniform convergent families of functions on R, aka {fn}, are also equicontinuous? What theorem says that uniform convergence implies equicontinuity? Please link.

Comment: You of course mean to assume that the $f_n$ are all continuous. The result is correct on a compact set (it's the usual $\epsilon/3$ argument), but almost surely wrong on $\Bbb R$ (what if the limit function is not uniformly continuous?).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggests, it is true that a uniformly convergent family of continuous functions on a compact set, $\{f_n\}$, is equicontinuous.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Notice that $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \le |f_n(x) - f_N(x)|+|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|+|f_n(y)-f_N(y)|$.

Choose $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|f_n(x) - f_N(x)| < \epsilon /3$, by uniform continuity. So, we can make the first and third terms small, so long as $n$ sufficiently big.

Since $f_N$ is continuous on a compact set, it is uniformly continuous. Choose $\delta_N>0$ such that $|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|<\epsilon/3$ as long as $|x-y|<\delta_N$. Pick $\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_{N-1}$ in the same manner for $f_1,\ldots,f_{N-1}$, by their uniform continuity. Set $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_N)$. Notice that this $\delta$ depends solely on $\epsilon$ and the family of functions. Hence we have equicontinuity.

Why we need continuity is trivial. We need compactness to get uniform continuity.